# exclude value from one select box based on value of other selectbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to exclude from one select list what the user has chosen in the other select list.

It is a list of 2 questions and the user can not select the same question in both select lists

**For some reason it works for the first couple of selections but then it start altering the value of the second box to a value it was not. It works fine for a couple of selections on both but if you keep selecting between the 2 it start to return incorrect results**

Below is the jquery code but here is the [Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BsHHz/) to complete code

```
var q1 = "#q1";
var q2 = "#q2";
var questions = {"1":"Question 1","2":"Question 2","3":"Question 3","4":"Question 4"}

function rebuildList(option,id) {
    var currentValue = $(id).val();
    $(id).empty();
    $(id).append($('<option></option>').val(0).html("Select"));

    $.each(questions, function (key, value) {
        if (key != option) {
            $(id).append($('<option></option>').val(key).html(value));
        }
    });

    //set the value back to what it was before emptying the list
    var setter;
    if (currentValue == "") {
        setter = id + " option:eq(0)";
    } else {
        setter = id + " option:eq(" + currentValue + ")";
    }


    $(setter).prop('selected', 'selected');
}



$(document).ready(function () {
    $(q1).change(function () {
        rebuildList($(this).val(), q2);  
        return false;
    });

    $(q2).change(function () {
        rebuildList($(this).val(), q1);  
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain the exact issue you are facing.. i checked fiddle and second dropdown have value except selected firstdropdown value

Comment: Please explain your problem clearly. I don't see any issues.

Comment: see exact issue in bold in OP

Comment: I see the issue now. Looks like the issue happens at `setter = id + " option:eq(" + currentValue + ")";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens when you use `eq()`. I modifed that part and the code works fine,

```
if (currentValue == "") {
    $(id).val(0)
} else {
    $(id).val(currentValue)
}
```

Check here, http://jsfiddle.net/muthkum/BsHHz/3/